# Convert Text File contents into vector elements

Tags: java, file, vector, file-handling

Hello I am building a reservation system for railways. I have used `JTable` component in order to display reservation list and when admin clicks a particular row the data inside the row gets selected and stored into vector. Then I store the vector data into file for further use. But i cannot convert the file data again into vector Elements. I want each word inside file to be a vector element.

Can somebody help me with the Logic ?

My text file **resDetails.txt** contains:

ganesh

nagar

pune

Jan 7, 2021

How will I Store these strings as vector elements ?

```
Path path = Paths.get("c:\\yashodeep\\eclipse-workspace\\ReservationRailway\\resDetails.txt");
        try(BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(path, Charset.defaultCharset())) {
            String line = null;
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null) { 
                System.out.println(line); 
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
```

I have tried this code but it's not working !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to specify how is it not working in order to have more precise answers. In my answer I will presume that "not working" in this case means that you do not build a `Vector` successfully. Using this as a starting point, let's see how can we create a `Vector` of `String` elements:

```
Vector<String> v = new Vector<String>();
v.add("foo");
```

So far, so good. Now, assuming that `line` always contains a proper `String`, let's modify your code as follows:

```
Path path = Paths.get("c:\\yashodeep\\eclipse-workspace\\ReservationRailway\\resDetails.txt");
Vector<String> v = new Vector<String>();
        try(BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(path, Charset.defaultCharset())) {
            String line = null;
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null) { 
                System.out.println(line);
                v.add(line);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
```

Comment: Thanks I tried this and it worked !!
I just didn't knew how to add each line into vector as an element.
Thanks for your help!